# urlRouteProvider.otherwise leads to infinite loop in angular

Tags: angularjs

Routing in my angular app looks like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('Login',{
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
    controller:'LoginCtrl'

  })

  .state('Deployment',{
    url:'/deployment',
    templateUrl:'templates/deployment.html'
  })
  .state('Bill',{
    url:'/bills',
    templateUrl:'templates/bills.html'
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
           var $state = $injector.get('$state');
            $state.go('Login');
        });
//This line is the culprit. This does not happen if I change state to go to Deployment but I need it to be Login

});
```

I basically need to skip Login state and jump to Deployment state if $localstorage has userIfo.

```
Login.html 

<form name="loginform" ng-if="showForm()"></form>
```

$scope.showForm looks like this:

```
$scope.showForm = function(){
  console.log("called")
  if($localStorage.userInfo === null || $localStorage.userInfo === undefined){
   return true;
  }else{
    $scope.signInUser();
   return false;
  }
}
```

but the problem is that $scope.showForm keeps on getting called.

However, it does not happen if I change the urlRouterProvider.otherwise to Deployment state.

How do I solve the issue? Honestly I have tried almost everything but have not been able to sort it.

Answer (score 1):

`ngIf` directive gets called on every angular `digest` cycle. So instead of calling the `showForm` function in an `ngIf` directive, I suggest you do that in the `onEnter` event of the `Login` state.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('Login',{
    url:'/login',
    onEnter:["$state","$localStorage",function($state,$localStorage){
       if($localStorage.userInfo)
            $state.go("Deployment");
    }],
    templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
    controller:'LoginCtrl'

  })
```

Although there are lots of other (and maybe even better) ways to implement this feature, one may be using a parent `abstract` state which decides weather to dispatch the routing to `Login` state or not.

Comment: But I need to call a function attached to scope in LoginCtrl before changing the state to Deployment. How can I do that?

Comment: I understand that scope is not initialized by this time but there must be some way around it?

Comment: Okay, I guess I could use a variable here and then check the value inside of controller and if that's true, I would call the function attached to scope?

Comment: If you need to use something like `signInUser()` function in multiple scenarios then its a perfect example of a functionality you should probably put in a `service` or a `factory` somewhere :)

Comment: I actually do not need to call it from multiple locations, I understand how using a service would always help in the scenario but I have not been advised to do that and need to proceed with current architecture.Is there a way to pass a variable from stateprovider to controller?

Comment: If you only need that function for that exact scenario, then i think you could safely move that function to the `onEnter` event handler altogether.
passing data between controllers without services are a bad practice in the angular world. however you could use `$state`'s `data` property and set your variable in `onEnter` and then read it in `controller`
Bear in mind that this `data` property will be inherited by any/all child states that the parent state may have

Comment: No, I actually need it attached to scope. I just need to have a boolean value being passed from onEnter to controller. Would that be possible?